# How are the definitions files loaded in typescript

Tags: typescript

in the past, d.ts files in typescript were only loaded when specifically required with a `///<reference path="...` statement. However, it's my understanding that this has changed recently and the compiler is now able to automatically load some local definition files. I have tried to find the rules for this by googling and browsing the TS specifications but with no success for the moment.

Anyone would be kind enough to explain theses rules or to point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These days everyone uses `tsconfig.json`, either [original](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) or [atom-flavored](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md) (in Atom editor).

When using `tsconfig.json`, you can omit files list and typescript compiler will compile all `*.ts` files it will find in any subdirectory, including `*.d.ts`.

Excluding files via `exclude` is [on the way](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3188), as well as [files globbing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3232).

If you don't want to use `tsconfig.json` or need files globbing right now, you can achieve similar behavior using [`gulp`](http://gulpjs.com/) with [`gulp-typescript`](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript) and [`gulp-filter`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter).

Comment: + very well researched answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that if i a project with "packages" (meteor) whose scope i want to control, i need to put a tsconfig.json in each package directory, or else tsc will consider the whole project ?

Comment: You only need one `tsconfig.json` in your root src directory. To get meteor working, place `meteor.d.ts` next to `tsconfig.json` or in any subdirectory.

Comment: @zlumer : when you work with meteor with packages, you have to deal with the way meteor treat global variables : there is file scope and package scope. Typescript doesn't play well with that.
With auto-importing of definitions, if you have only one tsconfig.json at the root of the project, typescript will consider that all declared variables classes and interfaces are in the global scope, but there are not. 
So i think that perhaps the solution would be to put one tsconfig. json per package. What would you think of that ?

Comment: @VincentJ it may work, but be prepared that you'll have to separately run TypeScript compiler for every `tsconfig.json` you've got.